# Stellar Validator Discovery

Tags: scp, validators

I'm setting up a Stellar network of 3 validator nodes in AWS EC2 instances. I use a private networkPassphrase ('MyOwnNetwork') (intentionally).

key entries of stellar-core.cfg:

```
RUN_STANDALONE=false
VALIDATORS=["$node1","$node2","$node3"]
PREFERRED_PEERS_ONLY=false
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=[
"MYPUBLICKEYOFNODE1 node2",
"MYPUBLICKEYOFNODE2 node3",
]
```

Question is how does each validator discover other nodes for consensus. Who translates PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS to their IP:ports? Should i enable some capability in AWS for each  node to discover others?